# Как сделать несколько TextField в тексте?

Tags: swift

Хочу сделать игру для изучения иностранного языка. Не знаю как лучше сделать чтобы было в предложение или в текст одно или несколько textField для проверки слова. Я  в начале делаю верстку экрана используя UIView. Потом вставляю UILabel и позиционирую UITextFiled в нужном месте над текстом, использую CGRect. Буду признателен за любую помощь. Спасибо.

Comment: Посмотрите здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67388508/inline-button-and-or-textfield-within-string-which-wraps-the-same-as-text-using, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40608696/ios-how-to-insert-uitextfield-inline-within-uitextview